# How to populate combobox and select item from db

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access, datagridview

I have a datagridview that I am populating from an Access db. I am able to fill the first two columns from the main table into 'TextBoxColumn1' and 'TextBoxColumn2'. The problem I am having is with the join table(s) that will populate a combobox (cmbCol1).

How do I get the combobox to fully populate from the join table and then select the item based on its ID?

SQL:

> SELECT ProdInv.lUniqueID AS ProdID, ProdInv.progname as ProgName,
>   FeatureType.luniqueID AS FeatID, FeatureType.strType AS FeatType,
>   ProdInv.Filename, prodinv.Mon, prodinv.Tue, prodinv.wed, prodinv.Thu,
>   prodinv.fri, prodinv.sat, prodinv.sun, prodinv.chkplay,
>   prodinv.CartFileName, prodinv.TrnsfrTIme, prodinv.AirTime,
>   prodinv.SponsoredBy, prodinv.ScheduledBy, prodinv.MinistryContact,
>   prodinv.Producer, prodinv.ProductionContact,
>   distributor.strDistributor, prodinv.DistributionContact,
>   automantype.strtype, WebFTPType.strtype
>       FROM 
>       ((((ProdInv LEFT JOIN FeatureType ON FeatureType.[lUniqueID]=ProdInv.FeatureTypeID) 
>       LEFT JOIN distributor ON distributor.[lUniqueID]=ProdInv.distributor_id) 
>       LEFT JOIN automantype ON automantype.[lUniqueID]=ProdInv.automanid) 
>       LEFT JOIN WebFTPType ON WebFTPType.[lUniqueID]=ProdInv.webid) 
>       LEFT JOIN triggerType ON triggerType.[lUniqueID]=ProdInv.trigger_id

```
        Dim cn As New OleDbConnection(strConn)

        cn.Open()

        ds = New DataSet
        da.Fill(ds, "ProdInv")

        cn.Close()

        dgrMain.AutoGenerateColumns = False
        dgrMain.DataSource = ds.Tables("ProdInv").DefaultView

        Dim TextBoxColumn1 As New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
        TextBoxColumn1.HeaderText = "ID"
        TextBoxColumn1.Width = 50
        TextBoxColumn1.DataPropertyName = "ProdID"

        Dim TextBoxColumn2 As New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
        TextBoxColumn2.HeaderText = "Program Name"
        TextBoxColumn2.Width = 200
        TextBoxColumn2.DataPropertyName = "ProgName"

        Dim cmbCol1 As New DataGridViewComboBoxColumn
        With cmbCol1
            .HeaderText = "Feature Type"
            .DataPropertyName = "FeatureType"
            .DisplayMember = "strType"
        End With

        dgrMain.Columns.Add(TextBoxColumn1)
        dgrMain.Columns.Add(TextBoxColumn2)
        dgrMain.Columns.Add(cmbCol1)
```

**UPDATE**
I realized that I was trying to do 2 things at the same time while loading the initial values into the datagridview.

Now instead of all the joins I just now do:
     SELECT * FROM ProdInv

I found that if I break it into 2 parts that it appears to work (keep reading):

1. Populate the combobox
2. Select the items from the combox in each row.

**Part 1**
Here is the code functions called while the form is loading:

```
Private Sub FillCombobox(strHeaderText As String)
    Dim cboBox As New DataGridViewComboBoxColumn

    With cboBox
        .HeaderText = strHeaderText
        .DataPropertyName = "strType"
        .DataSource = Populate("select * from featuretype")
        .ValueMember = "strType"
    End With

    dgrMain.Columns.Add(cboBox)
End Sub

Private Function Populate(ByVal sqlCommand As String) As DataTable
    Dim da = New OleDbDataAdapter(sqlCommand, strConn)
    Dim con As New OleDbConnection(strConn)

    con.Open()
    Dim command As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(sqlCommand, con)
    da.SelectCommand = command

    Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable()
    da.Fill(dt)
    con.Close()

    Return dt
End Function
```

**Part 2**
This section works **only** when I place a button on the form and press it **after** the form has loaded.

```
Private Sub SelectItemInCbobox(strSQL As String, nColNum As Integer)
    'Dim SQL As String = "Select FeatureTypeID (Select strType From FeatureType where ProdInv.FeatureTypeID = FeatureType.lUniqueid and Prodinv.lUniqueid) from prodinv"
    Dim nRowIndex As Integer = 0
    'Dim nColNum As Integer = 2
    '
    Dim dt As DataTable = Populate(strSQL)

    Try
        Do While nRowIndex < dt.Rows.Count
            If dt.Rows(nRowIndex).Item(0).ToString <> String.Empty Then
                dgrMain.Rows(nRowIndex).Cells(nColNum).Value = dt.Rows(nRowIndex).Item(COLUMN_0).ToString
            End If
            nRowIndex += 1
        Loop

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End Try
End Sub
```

When I try calling this during this while the form is loading it does not work.  In debug it steps through this section beautifully but still does not display the value in each of the comboboxes.

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated especially why it works one way but not the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought I was calling the routine to populate the form in the form_load but instead it was in the:

```
Public Sub New()
    InitializeComponent()
    GetData()
End Sub
```

Once I moved GetData() in the form_load it works and works well (See above for full details of what I posted earlier).

Answer (score 0):

The combobox needs to be filled separately with the features and bound to your grid.

```
Private cmbCol1 As DataGridViewComboBoxColumn
Private dtFeatureTypes as New DataTable

dtFeatureTypes = you need to get the list of features to display in the combobox

cmbCol1 = dgrMain.Columns("FeatureType")
With cmbCol1
        .HeaderText = "Feature Type"
        .DataPropertyName = "FeatureType"
        .DisplayMember = "strType"
        .ValueMember = "idType"    with the values 
        .DataSource = dtFeatureTypes
End With
```

Comment: I am getting it to populate but it is still not selecting the the item in the combobox based on the ID in the main table (ProdInv). Any thoughts?

Comment: I'd try making the ValueMember and the DataPropertyName the same column name.

Comment: I have tried doing everything and still to no avail. I can get the combo to populate, which is the easy part, or so it seems. However, I am still unable to get it select the strType based on the ID.  I did try making  the ValueMember and the DataPropertyName same also to no avail.  The following works in Access but at run time it still does not select the item:                              select featureid (Select strtype from featuretype where prodinv.featuretypeid = featuretype.luniqueid) from prodinv

Answer (score 0):

To populate a combobox directly with a query you can do it this way:

```vb
dim sqlStatement as String

sqlStatement = "SELECT [...] FROM [...] JOIN " 'your SQL statement here

cboBox.RowSourceType = "Table/Query"
cboBox.RowSource = sqlStatement
```

But you can also pass the name as string of a query designed in Access.